# JSX: Auto-fix empty string braces with plain string i.e., text={''} to text=""

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, eslint, prettier

A nit we often have during code-review is when there is a situation like this:

```
const Outer = () => {
  return <Inner text={''} />
};
```

which we would like to convert to:

```
const Outer = () => {
  return <Inner text="" />
};
```

It would be ideal if we could auto-fix `text={''}` to `text=""`.

Perhaps there is a way with ESLint or Prettier?

Comment: Just heads up - you can write your own rules and fixes for ESLint as plugins. So, if what you want here doesn't exist (I honestly don't know if it does or not), that can be an option.

Comment: This might be related to your formatter if you use one.

Comment: @Shivam we are using Prettier, so a solution with that tool would also be desirable